# read  write JSON in ExtJS

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have below javascript object handy with me. I want to read it and display on HTML page.

```
var info={
  "name":"Christina",
  "age":25;
  "city":"Chicago",
  "post":"CMO"  
};
```

I want to display above information with ExtJS api.

```
<ul>
 <li>Name is ...Christina </li>
 <li>Age is ... 25</li>
 <li>City is ... Chicago</li>
 <li>Post is ... CMO</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Ext.Template](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Template) class for this purpose. The code should be like

```
var t = new Ext.Template([
'<ul>',
 '<li>{name}</li>',
 '<li>{age}</li>',
 '<li>{city}</li>',
 '<li>{post}</li>',
'</ul>'
]);
t.compile();
t.append('some-element', info);
```